# API endpoint documentation no appearing using swagger and express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I am writing my API documentation using Swagger. I have successfully set up Swagger on my express project but the documentation for the endpoint doesn't show whenever it's on another route file apart from app.js file

Below is my App.js file

```js
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')
require('./db/db')

const app = express()
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");

// Extended: https://swagger.io/specification/#infoObject
const swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        info: {
            title: "MY API TITLE",
            description: "API Documentation",
            contact: {
                name: "Cali"
            },
            servers: ["http://localhost:3000"]
        }
    },
    // ['.routes/*.js']
    apis: ["app.js"]
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api/doc", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs, {explorer: true}));

app.use(express.json())
app.use(userRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Below is my users route file

```js
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/User')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')

const router = express.Router()

const swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");


router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerJsdoc));


/**
 * @swagger
 * /customers:
 *  get:
 *    description: Use to request all customers
 *    responses:
 *      '200':
 *        description: A successful response..
 */
router.get('/customers', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Welcome to Customers page');
})
```

What am I doing wrong?
PS: I am new to Swagger

Answer (score 6):

Have you find the answer for your issue?

I was fighting with some similar scenario and i have realized that at this line:

```
// ['.routes/*.js']
    apis: ["app.js"]
```

you need to specified the absolute path where all your **js route files** are. You can also use regular expressions!

My project structure is:

```
-/src
--/app
----/routes
------login.route.js (here is my **login route** with the @swagger notation)
------user.route.js (here is my **user route** with the @swagger notation)
```

So my regular expression will be

```
apis: ['./src/app/routes/**.js'],
```